# Searching with Multiple drop down with different criteria

Tags: php, sql

I am making query using drop down menu i.e (Where Clause) But the problem in my code is that here all the field values must be equal to the one selected in drop down menu.
I.e select * tablename Where marks = 200, I am not able to search like select * tablename Where marks > 200 etc.
Here is my code

```
$conditions = '';

$fields = array('name', 'marks', 'Country', 'city');
foreach ($fields as $field)
if ($tmp = urldecode($_GET[$field]))
$conditions .= ($conditions != '' ? ' AND ' : '') . $field . ' = \'' . mysql_escape_string($tmp) . '\'';
$total = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query('SELECT * FROM result' . ($conditions != '' ? 'WHERE ' . $conditions : '')));
```

Comment: you have 4 columns in your array and you cannot put directly a greater than condition in it, put some condition if the field is marks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the `$conditions` line with:

```
if ($field == "marks") {
    $conditions .= ($conditions != '' ? ' AND ' : '') . $field . ' > \'' . mysql_escape_string($tmp) . '\'';
} else {
    $conditions .= ($conditions != '' ? ' AND ' : '') . $field . ' = \'' . mysql_escape_string($tmp) . '\'';
}
```

Comment: If a user will search with Name select box, I think it will not work

Comment: You didn't mention anything about a `Name` dropdown in your OP. That's why You should post ALL of your code and be more specific!